# Issue with saving canvas as PNG

Tags: jquery, html, canvas, save, png

We are using fabric.js for one TShirt design portal. 
When I use `canvas.toDataURL('image/png')` on any button click it gives me **"DOM exception 18"** on Google Chrome only. Working very good on firefox.

What is the way to save canvas as PNG which supports on chrome also ?

Comment: ek kam kar screen shot ghe ani rename karun serverla upload kar...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are experiencing a Chrome security error that occurs when you try to use toDataUrl to save an image that was retrieved from another domain.

This is "affectionately" know as a CORS error (Cross-origin Resource Sharing).

Chrome is doing this to prevent a hacker taking an image of your banking login screen and using it to steal your banking password.

You can satisfy Chrome by originating the image you're trying to save on the same domain as the toDataURL call.

Alternatively, you can set the server that's hosting the image to allow cross-origin requests.

Here's a blog article on how to do that:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/